# Which one is better olympus omd em 10 or Sony alpha 6000

Tags: comparison

Which camera is better?
Olympus omd em-10 or Sony alpha 6000. I want to use it while travelling and need better low light performance

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based: they both have their strengths and weaknesses. "Which is better" isn't a question we can answer unless you tell us what you want to use the camera for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See here for a detailed comparison](http://snapsort.com/compare/Olympus-OM-D-E-M10-vs-Sony-Alpha-A6000). You have to reevaluate the pros and cons they mention based on your own preferences, you should not take the overall rating at face value. E.g. if I were to choose then the fact that the Olympus has a significantly higher resolution screen  (1,400k dots vs 921k dots) would not matter one iota to me, but for someone else that may well be a big deal.

Comment: Which one do you think is better in low light?

Comment: The Sony A6000 loooks better. It has lower noise at higher ISO settings and it has a better image stabilization method. These are two important factors are going to give the SonyA6000 the edge. Then you also have that the A6000 has a larger dynamic range, this is also helpful as you can have bright objects in the background of an overall dark scene.